# Prevent escaping javascript in visual editor

Tags: javascript, escaping

I tried to put my JavaScript code directly to my blog content, but It seems WordPress escapes `[ ]` chars.

Input:

```
<p>Some content blah blah</p>

<script>
var locations = [{
    lat: 50.765688, 
    lng: 15.056265
},{
    lat: 50.765688, 
    lng: 15.056265}
];
</script>
```

Output:

```
var locations = &#091;{
  lat: 50.765688,
  lng: 15.056265,
  ...
```

Is there any way how to prevent escaping javascript code?

Answer (score 0):

Adding scripts directly to the content is not a good idea. You can disable escaping of content, but that is even a worse idea.

Here we have a couple of solutions.

### Using a plugin

The [PHP Code Widget](https://wordpress.org/plugins/php-code-widget/) allows you to add almost anything as a widget. If you have some text widgets, you can replace them with this, while also adding your script.

### Enqueuing the script

The proper way would be to enqueue them using `wp_enqueue_script`. To do so, save your scripts into `.js` file, and them enqueue them as follows:

```
add_action('wp_enqueue_scripts', 'enqueue_my_script');
function enqueue_my_script(){
    wp_enqueue_script('my-handle','URL-HERE');
}
```

You can also use a conditional such as `if ( is_single() )` to make sure it's only output on single posts.

### Adding the script directly to the template

This is another method which is legitimate, but not the best practice. Simply open your `single.php` file and paste your script inside it. You should use `<script></script>` tags too.